# How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++

Tags: c++, escaping, getline

I'm coding a program that reads data directly from user input and was wondering how could I read all data until ESC button on keyboard is pressed. I found only something like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

but need to add a portable way (Linux/Windows) to catch a ESC button pressed and then break a while loop. How to do this?

EDIT:

I wrote this, but still - works even if I press an ESC button on my keyboard:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ESC=27;
    std::string line;
    bool moveOn = true;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && moveOn)
    {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            if(line.at(i) == ESC)
            { 
                moveOn = false;
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2:

Guys, this soulution doesn't work too, it eats the first char from my line!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ESC=27;
    char c;
    std::string line;
    bool moveOn = true;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && moveOn)
    {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
        c = cin.get();
        if(c == ESC)
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can set a `const int ESC=27;`, then use `c=getch()` in your loop, then  check if `c` equals `ESC` to terminate.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: isn't getch(); only Windows solution ... ?

Comment: use cin.get() instead of getch()

Comment: @abhinav: doesnt work, see my edit

Comment: @Katie: Just put the character back in the line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int main() {
  string str = "";
  char ch;
  while ((ch = std::cin.get()) != 27) {
    str += ch;
  }

 cout << str;

return 0;
}
```

this takes the input into your string till it encounters Escape character

Answer (score 1):

After you read the line, go though all characters you just read and look for the escape ASCII value (decimal 27).

---

Here's what I mean:

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, line) && moveOn)
{
    std::cout << line << "\n";

    // Do whatever processing you need

    // Check for ESC
    bool got_esc = false;
    for (const auto c : line)
    {
        if (c == 27)
        {
            got_esc = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (got_esc)
        break;
}
```

Comment: did like you said, could you please see my edit and say if it works for you? cheers:)

Comment: @Katie : you should get one character at a time using cin.get() and break whenever you see ESC

Comment: @Katie No, I mean you should iterate over the string `line`. _Or_ read one character at a time using `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: changed it to: http://pastie.org/private/at3ujkuknnqjogqzp50gya but still something is not like I want it to be :/ it eats that character anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found that this works for getting input for the escape key, you can also define and list other values in the while function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h> 

#define ESCAPE 27

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int c = 0;

        switch ((c = _getch()))
        {
        case ESCAPE:
            //insert action you what
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    char ch;

    bool loop=false;
    while(loop==false)
    {  cin>>number;
       cout<<number;
       cout<<"press enter to continue, escape to end"<<endl;
       ch=getch();
       if(ch==27)
       loop=true;
    }
    cout<<"loop terminated"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that for not just ESC character in C++, but for any other character of the keyboard in any language, read characters that you input into an integer variable and then print them as integer.

Either that or search online for a list of the ASCII characters.

This will give you ASCII value of the key, and then it's plain simple

```
if(foo==ASCIIval)
   break;
```

> For the ESC character, the ASCII value is 27.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses user input i.e., "P or p" for Paying Car and "N or n" for Non-Paying car without pressing Enter each time for input. Similarly it uses ASCII code of ESC Key (which is 27) to terminate the program and shows balance on pressing ESC Key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>  

class tolltb
{
private:
    unsigned int TotalCars;
    double TotalCash;

public:
    tolltb()
    {
        TotalCars = 0;
        TotalCash = 0;
    }

    void payingCar()
    {
        TotalCars++;
        TotalCash += 0.50;
    }

    void nopayCar()
    {
        TotalCars++;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "Total cars: " << TotalCars << endl;
        cout << "Total cash: $" << TotalCash << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    tolltb tb;
    char input;

    do {
        cout << "Enter p for paying car, n for non-paying car, or Esc to exit: ";
        input = _getch();   //included in conio.h headerfile
                            //we don't have to press enter key every time we want to input

        if (input == 'p' || 'P')
        {
            tb.payingCar();
            cout << input << endl;
        }
        else if (input == 'n' || 'N')
        {
            tb.nopayCar();
            cout << input << endl;
        }
        else if (input == 27) // ASCII code for Esc key
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again." << endl;
        }
    } while (input != 27); // Esc input ASCII code

    cout << "T                  Tollbooth Summary " << endl;
    tb.display();

    return 0;
}
```