# C++ console not exiting as expected

Tags: c++

I have a small console application that takes user input and I have the following loop with continuously asks for user input until they either (a) enter their name and press enter or (b) press the escape key. For some reason when they press the escape key they then have to press enter and at that point only the loop ends, the console window still remains open, what am I missing? The code is below...

```
while (input.empty()) {

    cout << "Enter Something";

    getline(cin, input);

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
    {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);   // this should just close the console entirely, right?
    }

}
```

Comment: `getline` blocks waiting for input.  If you want to handle input asynchronously you'll need to use a different method.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `std::getline()` will block while it waits for input, so `GetAsynKeyState()` will never run while input is being read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetAsyncKeyState` is called after calling `getline`.  `getline` waits for the user to type some data and press enter (or rather it waits for a line of data ending in a newline to be read from standard input).  Only after `getline` is done does this code check whether the ESC key was pressed.

See this question for a way to do what you're trying to accomplish: [How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214753/how-to-read-until-esc-button-is-pressed-from-cin-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

I think putting getline() before the If test doesn't allow the latter to executed as the former results in a blocking I/O. Try this:

```
while (input.empty()) {
    cout << "Enter Something";
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);        
    }
    getline(cin, input);
}
```

Comment: Unless you've already pressed escape before you see the message it's the same issue.