# Why do I get ESC successfully only by _getch()?

Tags: c++

I want to do somethings when I press ESC. First I found this: [How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214753/how-to-read-until-esc-button-is-pressed-from-cin-in-c)
Then I tried to use cin.get() like answers in that question.

```
using namespace std;

const int ESC = 27;

char c;
c = cin.get();
if (c == ESC) {
  ...;
} else {
  ...;
}
```

But it never works! `cin.get()` can get 'a', '1', etc. It just doesn't work When I enter Esc. I've also tried `cin >> c` and couldn't catch Esc either.

Then I use int `_getch( void );` in `<conio.h>` instead of `cin.get()`. It works!

`_getch()` seems to be C-style function, therefore I don't like to use it in C++ codes. And I don't understand why `cin.get()` doesn't work in my code but it seems to work in others' according to answers in the previous link.

It's on `Windows`.

Besedes, it's my first time to ask a question in stackoverflow and I haven't mastered English well. Sincerely hope for your answers and comments if I mistook something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `std::cin.get()` reads characters from the console window, however it is not possible to actually 'write' the escape character; therefor it never catches it.

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/)

> Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to true). Then (if good), it extracts characters from its associated stream buffer object as if calling its member functions sbumpc or sgetc, and finally destroys the sentry object before returning.

To catch the escape key on `Windows`:

```
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
{
    //Escape key pressed
}
```

On `Linux` you probably have to just use `_getch( void );` but I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Thank you! `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)' successfully catch Esc on `Windows`.

Comment: Er...Which function can I use to check whether any key was pressed?

like this:
    while(1){
      if(AnyKeyPressed()){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {...}
        else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE)) {...}
        ......
      }
    }

Comment: while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
 {
  char c = std::cin.get();
 }

Comment: Uh...I see. Thanks for you help~