# Checking for keypress while still being able to type into a cin

Tags: c++, windows, keypress

I want to be able to check for a specific keypress, while still being able to type to a cin. I am stuck with this issue, and I don't know what to do at this point.

My code I want to check for a specific keypress in:

```cpp
void displayOptions() {

    system("cls");
    drawLine(120, '_');
    std::cout << "\n" << casinoTitle;
    drawLine(120, '_');
    std::cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  Options" << endl;
    drawLine(120, '_');
    std::cout << "\n\nReset money: reset" << endl;
    std::cout << "Add 100" << currency << " to your balance: deposit" << endl;
    drawLine(120, '_');
    std::cout << "Action: ";
    std::cin >> playerInput;

    if (playerInput == "reset" || playerInput == "Reset") { 
        optionReset();
    }

    if (playerInput == "deposit" || playerInput == "Deposit") {
        if (playerBalance == 0 || playerBalance < 0) {
            optionReset();
        }
        std::cout << "Your balance has to be 0" << currency << "." << endl;
        std::cout << "Your current balance is: " << playerBalance << currency << ".";
        std::cin.get(); std::cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which platform? It makes a big difference on how you can approach this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I'm trying to do it on Windows.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without seeing the code you are having trouble with. But have a look at the Win32 API [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) function, it maybe able to help you.

Comment: You didn't explain what you are trying to accomplish with this code. What "specific keypress" are you looking for exactly, and at what point in the code? Please provide more details about your real issue.

Comment: Sorry, It's my first time writing my own question on here. I want to detect the specific keypress (ESC) at "std::cin >> playerInput;" throughout the when you are typing to the code. By that I mean, that I want a constant check for the keypress while at that line of code.

Comment: Why do you want to check for ESC? If you just want the user to cancel input, they should be using the appropriate key sequence to break a `cin >>` read and set `cin.eof()` to true - CTRL+Z on Windows, CTRL+D on 'Nix, etc. Othrwise, why not just have the user type in `quit` or other similar command?

Comment: Yeah see, the thing is. I want it to go back a step in the program. Specifically I want it load a function.

Comment: [How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214753/)

Comment: A console cooked read (i.e. `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` in line- and processed input modes, which are enabled by default) doesn't get canceled by Ctrl+Z. The user still has to press enter to end the read. If the read is via `ReadFile` (not `ReadConsole`) and `Ctrl+Z` is the first character in the input after the user presses enter, then the console server sets the number of characters read to 0 before completing the request.