# How can I handle user's inputs and close program when user presses ESC key

Tags: c, windows, loops, user-input, calculator

I want to make a program that works endlessly until the user presses <kbd>ESC</kbd>. And I need to handle the user's input, because I input a value which should be an integer. How can I make this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num,factorial; 
    while(1){
        
        factorial = 1;
        printf("Enter Number : ");
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=num ; i++){ 
            factorial *= i;
        }
        printf("Factorial : %d\n",factorial); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program should calculate factorial of a given number.

I tried this, but it makes an endless loop.

```
if(scanf("%d", &sayi) != 1){
    printf("Error Occured.\n");
    continue; 
}
```

Comment: Enter the value as a string with `fgets`. If you can't convert it with `sscanf` (such as an empty line) then end the loop. That isn't ending with `Esc` but `Enter` if that will do. Otherwise you'll need to build your own number input function using unblocked input, or with `ncurses` or with MS VC `getch()`.

Comment: You can't do this with `scanf`. Don't try to use `scanf` for other than "quick and dirty" exercises and test programs.

Comment: You can't without a specialized library like `ncurses` or `readline`. Switch to `while (scanf("%d", &num) == 1) { ... }` and exit the loop by pressing CTRL + D (instead of ESC)

Comment: Please specify what platform (Windows, Linux, etc) you're on.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I'm using Windows

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for your comment, but What should I use instead of `scanf` ?

Comment: Related C++ question: [How to read until ESC button is pressed from cin in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14214753/12149471) This is not a duplicate, though, because the language is different (C++ instead of C) and that question does not target a particular platform, whereas this one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Microsoft Windows, it is not possible to detect the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key using the functions provided by the C standard library.

However, it is possible to do this with the following [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform)-specific functions:

- [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170)
- [`_getche`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=msvc-170)
- [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)

When using these functions, you will have to program basic input functionality yourself, though. This includes

- deciding when to echo the input back to the user and
- deleting the last character when the user presses the backspace key.

Therefore, if you are looking for a simple solution, this is probably not what you want. It would be easier to continue using the functions provided by the C standard library and to make the user do something else to indicate that they are finished, for example to tell the user to enter the number `-1` in this case.

If you want something slightly more elegant, for example to make the user enter `q` or `quit` instead of `-1` when they are finished, then you could use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`, in order to first read one line of input from the user as a string. You can then compare this string with `q` or `quit`, and only if this comparison fails do you attempt to convert the string to a number, for example using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//forward declaration of function
void get_line_from_user( char *buffer, int buffer_size );

int main()
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        char line[200], *p;
        long num, factorial = 1;

        //prompt user for input
        printf("Enter number, or \"q\" to quit: ");

        //read one line of input from user
        get_line_from_user( line, sizeof line );

        //determine whether user wants to quit
        if ( line[0] == 'q' )
        {
            printf( "Quitting program...\n" );
            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
        }

        //attempt to convert input string to a number
        num = strtol( line, &p, 10 );

        //verify that conversion was successful
        if ( p == line )
        {
            printf( "Input error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //perform calculations
        for( int i = 2; i <= num; i++ )
        { 
            factorial *= i;
        }

        //print the result
        printf( "Factorial : %ld\n", factorial ); 
    }

    return 0;
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input from the
//user. On failure, the function will never return, but will
//print an error message and call "exit" instead.
void get_line_from_user( char *buffer, int buffer_size )
{
    char *p;

    //attempt to read one line of input
    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, stdin ) == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error reading from input\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to find newline character
    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );

    //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
    //the buffer was not too small to store the entire line)
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //a missing newline character is ok if the next
        //character is a newline character or if we have
        //reached end-of-file (for example if the input is
        //being piped from a file or if the user enters
        //end-of-file in the terminal itself)
        if ( getchar() != '\n' && !feof(stdin) )
        {
            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character by overwriting it with
        //null character
        *p = '\0';
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Enter number, or "q" to quit: 5
Factorial : 120
Enter number, or "q" to quit: 3
Factorial : 6
Enter number, or "q" to quit: Test
Input error!
Enter number, or "q" to quit: 7
Factorial : 5040
Enter number, or "q" to quit: 5
Factorial : 120
Enter number, or "q" to quit: 6
Factorial : 720
Enter number, or "q" to quit: q
Quitting program...
```